# Should I introduce a parent class just to hold a data member?

Tags: oop

I am designing a set of small C++ classes which all implement a single interface. Let's call the interface `IHandler`. It has only one method.

There are a bunch of Handlers, one for each type in our domain. Let's call them `FooHandler`, `BarHandler` etc. There is also a `PassiveHandler`, which does nothing (this is used for domain objects who don't need to be handled).

So our hierarchy could look nice and flat like this:

```
IHandler
|-PassiveHandler
|-FooHandler
|-BarHandler
| (...)
|-BazHandler
```

However, all the handlers need a data member, let's call it `domainObject`, so I thought about extracting a common superclass `Handler` that just holds this object.

Also, all the handlers except `PassiveHandler` needs a second data member, let's call it `infoObject`, so I thought about extracting another common superclass `ActiveHandler`to hold this object. Now the hierarchy is looking a lot deeper, but we have removed some duplication.

```
IHandler
|-Handler
| |-PassiveHandler
| |-ActiveHandler
|   |-FooHandler
|   |-BarHandler
|   | (...)
|   |-BazHandler
```

Would you go with the shallow design, where the `domainObject` member declaration is duplicated in all classes, and the `infoObject` member declaration in most? Or would you prefer the more complicated hierarchy, where duplication is removed? Is it worth it just for these data members?

Comment: (+1) For adding a "PassiveHandler" (Null Object / Null Method Design Pattern), sometimes a "0" means a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd choose the second, more hierarchical solution. Not only because the data member, but also because of your remark: "this is used for domain objects who don't need to be handled". Sounds like this is more like a nul-handler, which does nothing at all. Seems to be a good thing to pull it out of the tree, because you're likely to introduce other functionality too that will only apply to 'active handlers'.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an abstract class as the base type instead of a pure interface? This way you can both have a common ancestor and have your `domainObject` common to all base classes.

In my experience, pure OO can never be achieved when used in the trenches of development. There always must be some less-than-perfect solutions, but a case like this, where you simplify the inheritance hierarchy is a good example of when to bend the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 4 layers in total for your hierachy is not very deep ;D

However as a possible other solution: you could perhaps make 2 template classes for ActiveHandler and PassiveHandler both only inheriting the handler method from IHandler and use the template parameter to hold the data you want to hold.

I once needed to something like this and in the end it was very powerfull as I had an array of such handlers somewhere. So all where instanciated at the same place and it was super elegant to add a new handler which was a variation of an already existing one by writing a new helper class to use as template argument.

Comment: That won't work in my case unfortunately, since the handler methods will have different logic for each type of domain object.